# Function defined recursively computable in polynomial time

Tags: computational-complexity, recursion

Supose I define a function $f$ as
$$\begin{cases}f(0)=1\\f(n+1)=p(f(0)+\dots+f(n))\end{cases}$$
where $p$ is some function computable in polynomial time.

Can I say that $f$ is also computable in polynomial time?

I saw [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01201998) paper with a recursion-theoretic characterization of $\mathsf{FP}$ but didn't manage to use this characterization to prove/disprove this claim.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you might try the [computer science stack](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Polynomial in $n$ or in $\log n$? The former is easy; the latter is probably impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean $f$ and $p$ are computable in poly(log(input)) time, i.e. polynomial in the length of the input as a binary string.

Let $p(n)=(n+1)^2$ which is definitely computable in $O(\log^2(n))$ time. It's easy to show that $f(n)\ge 2^n$ by induction: whenever $n\ge 1$ $$f(n+1)= (f(0)+\cdots+f(n)+1)^2 \ge f(n)^2 \ge (2^n)^2 = 2^{2n}\ge 2^{n+1}$$

Therefore even to write down the answer $f(n)$ bit by bit takes at least $\log_2 f(n)\ge n$ steps, which is exponential in $\log(n)$.

**P.S.** If you mean polynomial in $n$, then let $p(n) = 2^n$ which is computable in poly($n$) time. If $f(n)$ is computable in $q(n)$ time for a polynomial $q$, then $f(n)\le 2^{q(n)}$ because in $\le q(n)$ time, one can write down at most $2^{q(n)}$-bits. Then for all $n$, $$f(n+1) = p(f(0) + f(1) + \cdots + f(n)) = 2^{f(0)+f(1)+\cdots+f(n)}\le 2^{q(n+1)}$$ $$f(n)\le f(0)+\cdots+f(n)\le q(n+1)$$ but $f(n)$ grows way faster than exponential function $2^n$, so it cannot be bounded by a polynomial.

So either way, the answer is false.